# Facebook access token expire after two months

Tags: facebook

I am working on Facebook connectivity with my site.Problem is that the access token which I get is expire after two months then How do we get new access token of user we need again authenticate the user or there is some another way for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are requesting offline access, they should not expire. Are you sure they expire after 2 months.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Offline access_token have infinite lifetime.

I guess, may be user is changing his/her password. If a user changes his/her password, access_token expires.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is send your user to the auth page or the auth dialogue.

Easiest way with php and Facebook PHP SDK:

Get the login URL:

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginURL(array('scope' => 'publish_stream, publish_actions, AND_MORE_PERMISSIONS'));
header('location:' . $url);
```

With JavaScript and Facebook JS SDK:
Call the following function:

```
FB.login()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a new access token in case your access token expire. When you redirect the user to the auth dialog, the user is not prompted for permissions if the user has already authorized your application.

However if a user has de-authorized your application then user will need to re-authorize your application for you to get the access_token.

See this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/). It describes problems and solution for all scenarios. Hope it helps